# Destroying a COM object from .NET application

Tags: c#, c++, .net, com

I have a legacy COM component which I am trying to use from a .NET windows form application.  I used `aximp.exe` to create a .NET wrapper for the unmanaged COM component. Then I use `ISupportInitialize` interface's `BeginInit` and `EndInit` to create an instance of the COM class. This is working fine. But when I try to destroy the object using `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` the unmanaged C++ COM object's destructor is not getting called. I tried `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` also but still the destructor is not getting called. Can anybody tell me what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: This probably means that you have other outstanding references to the object. Are you sure there aren't any?

Comment: Thanks .. but how do I find there are other references?

Comment: if you own the implementation of the COM object (and I guess you have as you sys that the destructor is never called), you can monitor AddRef/Release calls and reference count.

Answer (score 0):

The wrapper will implement `IDispose`.

A WinForm class typically has a components collection and a Dispose method that disposes of the components. You can add your object to the components collection and it will be disposed with the form. (You might even let the form designer generate all the code for you.)

If you want to do it earlier, just call `Dispose` on the object (such as in a `finally` block or implicitly via a `using` statement).

Comment: I am calling FinalReleaseCOMObject from Dispose only . . I am manually calling Dispose from my winform application

Comment: You should let aximp.exe and the System. System.Windows.Forms.AxHost-derived wrapper it generated do the work for you. If you are using Visual Studio or equiv, let the WinForm designer generate code for the lifetime of your component. It's as simple as adding a project reference to a COM object, adding the control to the WinForms toolbox, and dragging it to your Form. It be more maintainable that way. If you have a special case, try it that way first and then develop your special case.